# Azure table storage: maximum variable size?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-table-storage

I will be using the table storage to store a lot of blob names, in a single string, appended to each other using some special character. This string will sky rockets pretty soon. But is there a maximum size to the length of a property for a particular entity ? in my case the string ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maximal string size for a single property is 64kb. If you take the [Fat Entity](https://github.com/Lokad/lokad-cloud/wiki/FatEntities) approach as defined by Lokad.Cloud, then you can have 1mb property instead (leveraging the maximal entity size instead).

Answer (score 8):

Maximum string size is 64kb - an individual entity cannot exceed 1mb.